# macOS Accessibility Inspector does not work with Slack

Tags: macos, accessibility, accessibility-inspector

When I'm using macOS's Accessibility Inspector on apps like notes and Apple mail, I get all the window's children elements. If I use the Inspector on Slack, though, I only get the window and nothing of the content.

Is there a way to force slack to expose its children to the inspector somehow?
Same goes for WhatsApp Web and the Apple Pages Canvas.

Comment: I doubt it.  They are most likely web apps displayed in a MacOS window, so there are no (native) MacOS elements to retrieve, only HTML DOM elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/accessibility#macos

The `AXManualAccessibility` Attribute of the App must be set to `kCFBooleanTrue`.

This is how it's done:

1. Get the process ID of the current app
2. Create an `AXUIElement` from the app using the process ID
3. Set the `AXManualAccessibility` of the newly created AXUIElement to `kCFBooleanTrue`

**Now all elements of the App are inspectable using the Accessibility manager. This not only works for all electron apps, but also apps like Pages or MS Word.**

**Swift**

```swift
let kAXManualAccessibility: CFString = "AXManualAccessibility" as CFString;

private func enableAccessibility() {
    guard let processIdentifier = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication?.processIdentifier else { return }
    let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(processIdentifier)

    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(appRef, kAXManualAccessibility, kCFBooleanTrue)
}
```

**Objective C**

```objectivec
CFStringRef kAXManualAccessibility = CFSTR("AXManualAccessibility");

+ (void)enableAccessibility:(BOOL)enable inElectronApplication:(NSRunningApplication *)app
{
    AXUIElementRef appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app.processIdentifier);
    if (appRef == nil) return;

    CFBooleanRef value = enable ? kCFBooleanTrue : kCFBooleanFalse;
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(appRef, kAXManualAccessibility, value);
    CFRelease(appRef);
}
```